# Using data in a .txt file as a constraint against a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I am looking for some advice, I am looking to see if it is possible to use the date & time from a text file generated from a batchfile code in the batchfile sets the date as the following:

```
set datetimef=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2% %time%
echo %datetimef% >C:\Desktop\Andy\DateTime1.txt
```

the output outout is the following format:
2013-03-07 13:04:55.02

to use against the StartTime of a SQL tracefile, so eventually it would end up being something like

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
go
select StartTime from fn_trace_gettable ('C:\desktop\Andy\AndyTestTrace3.trc', default) 
WHERE StartTime >= **--the value from the DateTime1.txt file--**
```

If i specify the time it works no problem, however the datetime1.txt file is generated everytime another batch file is run and the idea is to display the traces that have taken place since the last batch file was run as it outputs the data from the tracefile into a flat file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am wondering how would i go about using the data from the textfile to query it against the tracefile?

Comment: Are you generating the SQL inside a batchfile?

Comment: the batchfile executes a SQLCMD which executes a query held in a .SQL file: 

sqlcmd -E -iC:\Desktop\Andy\AndyQuery2.sql -s"," -W -oC:\Desktop\Andy\AndyTraceFileOutput.txt 

and the query in the .SQL file is: 

SET NOCOUNT ON; go select StartTime from fn_trace_gettable ('C:\desktop\Andy\AndyTestTrace3.trc', default) WHERE StartTime >=

Comment: If the batch file were to recreate the .SQL file every time, it would be trivial to place the relevant dateTime into it as a hardcoded constant.

Comment: You could still have a template file with say a .SQL_TMP extension holding the bulk of the SQL.

Comment: it is just there as a means to allow an old version of netcool to read the data as the version does not read trace tables, the .SQL file isnt created every time it just runs the sql file. The time itself constantly changes when the file is automatically run by contab every x minutes

Comment: Yes! So CREATE the .SQL file anew every time, with the correct hard-coded time. Problem solved.